# NodeJS Return Back

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, passport.js

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle errors with NodeJS. I need to return back (Or display an error and not redirect) if there is an error with either the user signing up or their credit card being accepted. The problem is I get the error "Cannot set headers after they're already set" if I try to use more than one res.redirect. How do I get around this. I've shown the locations where I want to redirect below.

Thanks!

```
app.post('/quiz', function(req, res) {


        var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
        var charge = stripe.charges.create({
         amount: 749,
         currency: "usd",
         description: "Example charge",
         source: token,

        }, function(err, charge) {
            if(err) {
              console.log('Did not charge or create error' +  err);

           // return res.redirect('/');
        //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
            }
            console.log('charged')
            var user = new User({
          username: req.body.username,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
          datapoint: req.body.datapoint
        })

      user.save(function(err) {
        console.log('this is the problem' + ' ' + err)
        // return res.redirect('/');
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
       //I WANT TO RETURN TO HOME HERE IF THERES AN ERROR
    });

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
              if(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              console.log('all looks good')
              // If everything looks good I want to redirect to the next page
              // If everything looks good I want to redirect to the next page
              // If everything looks good I want to redirect to the next page
              // If everything looks good I want to redirect to the next page
              // res.redirect('/jobquiz');
            });
        });
      });
```

Comment: you need show where your doing "response.send()" stuff .. or did you comment out "res.redirect('/jobquiz') after you got that above error?

Comment: Right. The 3 places where it is commented out is where I'm trying to redirect.